# keyCloak: (wrong ISS) or (wrong audience), in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, keycloak, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I want to validate the JWT token for all the controller access points buy using KeyCloack.

Sometimes I get this error:

> WARN [Keycloak] Cannot validate access token: Error: Grant validation failed. Reason: invalid token (wrong audience)

or

> WARN [Keycloak] Cannot validate access token: Error: Grant validation failed. Reason: invalid token (wrong ISS)

I'm sending the token as a **bearer token in the header**

1. What is the difference between wrong ISS and wrong audience error?
2. Why do I'm getting this?
3. Any suggestions to resolve it?

**I'm new with NestJS and Keycloak, please guide me if I missed something.**

My approach:

env variable:

They keyCloak is deployed on a server whose URL is below:

```
## Authentication-related values
PEM_KEY_PATH='./src/auth/user-service.pem'
KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL='http://service.serveraws.io/realms/user-service'
KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL='http://service.serveraws.io/'
KEYCLOAK_REALM='user-service'
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID='user-kundali'
KEYCLOAK_SECRET='test'
```

> auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  KeycloakConnectModule,
  RoleGuard,
  AuthGuard,
  PolicyEnforcementMode,
  TokenValidation,
} from 'nest-keycloak-connect';

import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

@Module({
  imports: [ KeycloakConnectModule.register({
    authServerUrl: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL,
    realm: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    // clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    resource: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    verifyTokenAudience: true,
    secret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET,
    policyEnforcement: PolicyEnforcementMode.PERMISSIVE,
    tokenValidation: TokenValidation.ONLINE,
  }), ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RoleGuard,
    }
  ],
})

export class KeyCloakModule {
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import validationSchema from './config.schema';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { KeyCloakModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      name: 'default',
      type: 'mongodb',
      database: 'test-db',
      //url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      synchronize: true,
      entities: [],
      ssl: true,
      retryWrites: false
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema,
    }),
    UserModule,
    KeyCloakModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> my custom Jwt Auth instead of using authGuard: jwtGuard.service.ts

**I'm using pem key instead of the secret phrase, but I have tried with both the secret phrase and pem key, getting the same error.**

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const filePath = process.cwd();
const key = readFileSync(path.resolve(filePath, process.env.PEM_KEY_PATH));

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: key,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    console.log(" payload ::: ",payload)

    return { ...payload.user };
  }
}
```

> my user controller: user.controller.ts

```
import { Response } from 'express';
import {
  Res, HttpStatus,
  Controller, Get, Param, Query, UseGuards
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ApiBearerAuth,
  ApiCreatedResponse,
  ApiOperation,
  ApiTags,
  ApiParam,
  ApiQuery,
} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { UserServices } from './users.services';
import { UserModel } from './entity/user.entity';
import { AuthGuard, Roles, Unprotected } from 'nest-keycloak-connect';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../auth/jwtAuthGuard.service';

@ApiBearerAuth()
@ApiTags('Reports')
@Controller('reports')

export class UserController {
  constructor(
    private readonly userServices: UserServices
  ) { }

  // @Unprotected()
  @Get('/user-data/:username')
  // @Roles({ roles: ['admin', 'other', 'realm:sysadmin'] })
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Fetch kundali of a user.' })
  @ApiParam({
    name: 'username',
    description: 'username',
    required: true,
  })
  @ApiCreatedResponse({ type: UserModel, description: `fetch all the the data` })
  async getUserKundali(
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Param("username") username: string
  ): Promise<any> {

    const response = await this.userServices.getUserKundali(username);

    if (response && response.data) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(response);
    } else {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the steps from this tutorial as well. But still facing this error.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92EZ9lBK2pE

Comment: @sgClaudia98 no updates on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL to 'http://service.serveraws.io/auth/'.

It must end with /auth/.